# Need smooth animation with rounded corners of uiimageview

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I Have custom table view cell with image view that has rounded corners. My drawRect: code looks like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    _thumbnailImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    _thumbnailImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    _thumbnailImage.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    _thumbnailImage.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
```

But it's performance is horrible. I have about 40fps with this code and table view looks really choppy. If i delete 2 lines:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    _thumbnailImage.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    _thumbnailImage.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
```

My table view shows 60fps and it's scrolling very smooth.
I know that I am doing something wrong, cuz Twitter and other apps have rounded corners and smooth scrolling. Help me please.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to make rounded corners neither for UImageView, but for UIImage before using images in UITableViewCells. Now my scroll's fps is 50+ and it looks very smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the layer's properties inside `drawRect`. Try doing that once somewhere else.